# Can one say in a proof, without further justification, that card {a,b} = 1 implies a=b?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic

Is the inference from # {a,b} = 1 to a=b formally correct ?

An objection could be that the first statement, about cardinality, is quantitative, while the second about identity is somewhat qualitative.

Is there a fallacy risk here?

Remark : I ask the question after having been tempted to make this inference:

[What is wrong with this attempt at proving that : if X is equal to {a} then all the elements of X are equal to a ( and reciprocally)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3216164/what-is-wrong-with-this-attempt-at-proving-that-if-x-is-equal-to-a-then-all)

Comment: Again, you have to define what is the "cardinality" of a set.

Comment: We have to define a relation of "equipollence" between set : $A \sim B$ meaning that there is a bijection between them, and then state the axiom : $\text # A = \text # B \leftrightarrow (A \sim B)$.

Comment: Then we define : $n$ is a *cardinal number* if and only if there is a set $A$ 
such that $\text # (A ) = n$. Finally, we introduce some "names" : $0 = \text # (\emptyset)$, $1= \text # ( \{ \emptyset \} )$ and so on.

Comment: Now, from $\text # ( \{ a, b \} )=1$ and the def of $1$ we have that there is a bijection between $\{ a, b \}$ and $\{ \emptyset \}$, and this - with Extensionality -will be enough to conclude that $a=b$.

Comment: The only things that are "axiomatically evident" are instances of axioms.

Comment: How is $a=b$ "qualitative"?

Comment: @NoahSchweiber. The so called " numerical identity"  is qualitative in the sense that it is an extreme case of qualitative identity. "Numerical identity requires absolute, or total, qualitative identity, and can only hold between a thing and itself" ( Stanford encyclopedia, "Identity"). One could translate " a=b" as " For all quality Q, a has Q iff b has Q".  Traditionnally, quantitative properties are considered as extrinsic while qualitative ones are intrinsic. And it can be argued that identity is the most intrinsic property a thing can have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quantitative and qualitative statements have no logical distinction; that is not a concern here (except possibly philosophically, but you're on MathSE).

The inference directly from $\#\{a,b\} = 1$ to $a = b$, without any axioms or definitions to support it, is of course not logically valid; but that's just because there are no rules of reasoning related to the symbol $\#$. If you include a definition, it becomes clear.

One definition of $\#A = n$ is "there exists a bijective function $f$ with domain $A$ and range $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$." Under that definition, $\#\{a,b\}=1$ means "there exists a bijective function $f$ with domain $\{a,b\}$ and range $\{0\}$." But then $f(a) = 0$ and $f(b) = 0$, because $0$ is the only element in the range. So $f(a) = f(b)$. But $f$ is bijective and therefore injective, so by definition it must be that $a = b$. In other words: with definitions in place, this is a logically valid step of reasoning.

Comment: @Reese.Clear and usefull answer.

Comment: @Reese.I think that even in mathematics it can be usefull to make a difference between the qualitative meaning and the quantitative meaning of a statement. For example, from the fact that two rectilinear segments are both 5 cm long, a beginner could infer that they are equal ( though he can only infer that their lenghts are equal, not that they are identical). But that is just a detail.